# error TS7008: Member 'summary' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular, typescript

After Updating to Angular 2 RC I got the following error:

> error TS7008: Member 'summary' implicitly has an 'any' type.

in this line:

```
@Input() summary;
```

what's wrong?

**Edit:** Ok, seem like I get this error on ANY of my public variables.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Perhaps you changed the value of the `noImplicitAny` attribute in your TypeScript compiler configuration... See the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false // <-----
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

You could try to add a type on your property. Something like:

```
@Input() summary:string;
```

Comment: Oh! I understand well ;-) Check the `tsconfig.json` file in the `compilerOptions` block : `"noImplicitAny": false`...

Comment: Looks like "noImplicitAny" is set to true in the Angular2 quickstart package on Github now. That's broken a few tutorials...

Answer (score 26):

*This question already has correct answers, however to clarify and fully explain:*

**Solution 1** - Set this in your tsconfig.json:

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

**Solution 2** Define the type for your variable like this:

```
@Input() summary:string;
```

Explanation:

If you are converting plain JavaScript to TypeScript, you won't have any types assigned to your variables (or parameters) - since strict *typing* is what gives TypeScript its name.

In this case, when you have something like this variable (which has no type assigned):

```
@Input() summary;
```

Then TypeScript will implicitly assume that your variable has a type of 'Any' (i.e. it assumes that the variable can hold a value of *any* type). Furthermore, if you have the following set in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "noImplicitAny": true,
  }
}
```

... then this tells the TypeScript compiler to throw errors if a variable or parameter implicitly has the 'Any' type. So, you can use the 1st solution to ignore all 'implicit any' errors, *or* use the 2nd solution (supply a type), and 'any' will not be implied.

Reference for TypeScript compiler options:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 6):

just comment out this `"noImplicitAny": false` in `tsconfig` and it will work

Answer (score 5):

In Angular 12+ `"strict": false,` in tsconfig.json worked for me.

Comment: this will worked only for 12+ project.

Answer (score 2):

1. In tsconfig.json you should change:

```
"strict": false,
```

2. initialise your variable to `any`:

```
@Input() summary:any;
```

Answer (score -2):

declare variable like this:
summary: any;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29915242)