# Multiple Errors when using TypeScript + React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on my first project combining TypeScript and React, and I'm having some major issues just getting a simple test project to work.

Currently, I'm using the following (package.json):

```
{
  "name": "proxied-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "MTG proxies, powered by React/Apollo.",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.4",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  }
}
```

When I try to launch my project using `npm run dev`, I get the following slew of errors:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:15:33
    TS7006: Parameter 'obj' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:17:10
    TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:17:34
    TS7006: Parameter 'obj' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:17:202
    TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:17:237
    TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type '{}'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:7:60
    TS7006: Parameter 'target' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:7:68
    TS7006: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:7:368
    TS7006: Parameter 'Constructor' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:7:381
    TS7006: Parameter 'protoProps' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:7:393
    TS7006: Parameter 'staticProps' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:13:10
    TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:13:34
    TS7006: Parameter 'obj' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:13:202
    TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:13:237
    TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type '{}'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:15:26
    TS7006: Parameter 'instance' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:15:36
    TS7006: Parameter 'Constructor' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:17:37
    TS7006: Parameter 'self' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:17:43
    TS7006: Parameter 'call' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:19:20
    TS7006: Parameter 'subClass' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:19:30
    TS7006: Parameter 'superClass' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:25:14
    TS7023: 'Hello' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:28:56
    TS2339: Property '__proto__' does not exist on type '() => any'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Hello.tsx:31:5
    TS2554: Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.
```

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, I've followed a bit of documentation here and there, and I have the proper dependencies (I thought), including typings for React/ReactDOM, using what I believed was the correct syntax for things.

I feel like at some point in my code, I need to be explicitly setting the type on some stuff that the documentation missed, but I'm sort of lost (and new to TypeScript in general, but I'm stumbling through it).

This is the entry point for the application (index.tsx):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Hello from "./components/Hello";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And this is the component I am attempting to render:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface HelloProps {
    compiler: string,
    framework: string,
}

interface State {
    counter: number
}

class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, State> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <h2>Greetings from {this.props.compiler} and {this.props.framework}!</h2>
        )
    }
}

export default Hello;
```

This is the webpack configuration I am currently using:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: ['./src/index'],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            react: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/react')),
            'babel-core': path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/@babel/core'))
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
    ]
}
```

I'm just trying to figure out what I might be doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like AT-loader is trying to read from the transpiled code, and not the TS code, meaning the loaders in the webpack config might not be in the correct order, or some other issue relating to that. Could you share the webpack config?

Comment: Sure!   I'll edit the question and add the webpack config!

Comment: Added webpack configuration to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error TS7008: Member 'summary' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032857/error-ts7008-member-summary-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are happening because the code is being transpiled with babel, then that transpiled code is being fed into AT loader. Since you're transpiling with Babel, there's no need to put AT loader into the mix here. Remove it from your webpack rules:

```
    rules: [
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: ['babel-loader'] }
    ]
```

You'll still want to keep your tsconfig, of course, and you can run `tsc --noEmit` on the command line to typecheck without transpiling.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I dropped the loader from the chain, adjusted a problem I had with `html-webpack-plugin` and enabled HMR, and it all works as intended.

Thank you so much.   Answer accepted.  :)